# GKE pods not connecting to Cloudsql

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

My app can't seem to connect to the proxy thus my Cloudsql Database.

Below are my setup:

my-simple-app.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: web
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: default-pool
      containers:
      - image: joelaw/nameko-hello:0.2
        name: web
        env:
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: 127.0.0.1
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: password
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: username
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http-server
      - image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.09
        name: cloudsql-proxy
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/cloudsql",
                  "-instances=spheric-veric-task:asia-southeast1:authdb:5432",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
          - name: ssl-certs
            mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
          - name: cloudsql
            mountPath: /cloudsql
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
        - name: ssl-certs
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/ssl/certs
        - name: cloudsql
          emptyDir:
```

I had setup the secrets correctly I suppose.

Below are some data that I collected from the instance:

The pod live happily:

```
web-69c7777c68-s2jt6   2/2       Running   0          9m
web-69c7777c68-zbwtv   2/2       Running   0          9m
```

When I run: `kubectl logs web-69c7777c68-zbwtv -c cloudsql-proxy`

It recorded this:

```
2019/04/04 03:25:35 using credential file for authentication; email=auth-db-user@spheric-verve-228610.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2019/04/04 03:25:35 Listening on /cloudsql/spheric-veric-task:asia-southeast1:authdb:5432/.s.PGSQL.5432 for spheric-veric-task:asia-southeast1:authdb:5432
2019/04/04 03:25:35 Ready for new connections
```

Since the app is not configured to connect to the db, what I did is to ssh into the pod with:

```
kubectl exec -it web-69c7777c68-mrdpn -- /bin/bash
# Followed by installing postgresql driver:
apt-get install postgresql
# Trying to connect to cloudsql:
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U
```

When I run psql in the container:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can anyone of you kindly advise what should I do to connect to the DB?

Comment: In your kubectl exec command, I don't see you specifying which container within the pod you are connecting with.  Are you sure that you are connecting to the SQL Proxy container?

Comment: Is it linked to it by it self? Or I will have to create a service to link them? @Kolban. Thanks for responding

Comment: Maybe I created an instance of the proxy, but not connecting the two container?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the instance connection string wrong, and so the proxy is listening on a unix socket in the `/cloudsql/` directory instead of to a TCP port.

To tell the proxy to listen on a TCP port, use the following:

```
-instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:5432
```

Otherwise, the following format creates a unix socket (defaulting to the `/cloudsql` directory):

```
-instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

Comment: I believe you are correct and great find/knowledge ... here is a link to the GitHub page for the cloudsql-proxy which lists examples and command line options

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy

Comment: Thanks mate, manage to improve the situation, now when I check the proxy's log I got this:
2019/04/05 01:34:00 using credential file for authentication; email=auth-db-
2019/04/05 01:34:00 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for spheric-veric-task:asia-southeast1:authdb
2019/04/05 01:34:00 Ready for new connections.

But when I try to psql in my app container, I am still getting the same error:
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"?

Comment: @Joe.L -- make sure you tell postgres where you want it to connect to 127.0.0.1- `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: I tried psql to the host stated, but it still return the same error code. Not sure what's going on here

Comment: If it's the same error, the `psql` isn't following the flags. Maybe you need to specify the port as well? `psql -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1`